# Class casting and parentheses

Tags: android, casting, fragment

I have seen the following code suggested a number of times for allowing a fragment to access a variable in its activity.

```
foo = ((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).getFoo();
```

Now, if it looked like:

```
foo = (MainActivity)this.getActivity().getFoo();
```

if would make sense that it was being cast as (MainActivity), however, what does enclosing the entire left side in parentheses do exactly?

Thanks much,

-John

Comment: The first statement means cast the result of getActivity into a MainActivity instance and getFoo from that object instance, the second instance, I'm pretty sure will give you something weird, if not a class cast exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in maths, adding parentheses means "do this first". In the expression:

```
((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).getFoo();
```

We are saying that do this first:

```
(MainActivity)this.getActivity()
```

Then on the result of the above, do this:

```
.getFoo();
```

If we don't have the parentheses,

```
(MainActivity)this.getActivity().getFoo();
```

We are saying that do this first, since casting has a low precedence:

```
this.getActivity().getFoo()
```

then cast the result of the above to `MainActivity`.

Obviously, the latter expression does not work because there is no `getFoo` defined in `Activity`, which is what the `getActivity` returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's incorrect, because you can't call getFoo() on getActivity(), what returns default Activity class. You should call it as **((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).getFoo();**